# Jquery - Finding closest matching span isn't working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set a variable to match the text displayed inside the closest matching span. I've tried about 10 different ways, and when I alert it (to show what it's getting) it always either displays nothing or it says undefined.

Here is the html

```
<div class="list-group-item">
<span class="list-group-item-heading commenter-name">Test Name</span><span class="pull-right"><a id="78564610">Reply</a> <span class="small text-muted">Mar 29 2017, 00:59:57</span></span>
<p class="list-group-item-text">First comment on page.</p>
</div>
```

Here is the relevant jQuery (minus the on document ready etc)

```
$("a").click(function() {

    var $test = $(this).closest('.commenter-name').text();

alert($test);
```

I am trying to get $test to have the content of the span with the class 'commenter-name' - So $test should be set to "Test Name" in this case; but I always either get an empty response or undefined.

If I change it to something like this

```
var $test = $(this).closest('span').text();
```

It shows everything inside the CURRENT span (it would show `<a id="78564610">Reply</a> <span class="small text-muted">Mar 29 2017, 00:59:57</span>`), but for whatever reason I can't refer to that other span with the name in it.

There are several sets of the above HTML, but I don't see why that should matter since I've been trying both closest, parents, parent, prev, and find.

Comment: just an idea but have you tried, `$(this).prev('.commenter-name').text()` ?  if ofc your html structure always looks like this

Comment: Just tried that, and it still returns and alerts with nothing (empty). I've also tried the same format but with closest, and find instead of that

Comment: try this `$(this).parent().prev('.commenter-name').text();`

Comment: maybe  `$(this).parent().parent().find('.commenter-name').html()`

Comment: Closest starts with itself and goes up.  This span is a sibling of the parent node, $(this).parent().sibling(".commenter-name")

Comment: @guradio Tried that and it still shows an empty response.

Comment: check the demo below @Larry7

Comment: @Larry7 I tried the Guradio demo and it is perfect. What else you are expecting to get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) doesn't literally means closest. the method traverse up the hierarchy. As its not the parent of ANCHOR you are not getting the result;

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

*Use*

```
var $test = $(this)
            .closest('.list-group-item') //Target  common parent
            .find('.commenter-name') //target the element
            .text();
```

```js
$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $test = $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.commenter-name').text();
  console.log($test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group-item">
  <span class="list-group-item-heading commenter-name">Test Name</span><span class="pull-right"><a href="#" id="78564610">Reply</a> <span class="small text-muted">Mar 29 2017, 00:59:57</span></span>
  <p class="list-group-item-text">First comment on page.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works and it now gets the proper HTML :)

Will mark this as the answer as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("a").click(function() {

  var $test = $(this).parent().prev('.commenter-name').text();

  alert($test);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group-item">
  <span class="list-group-item-heading commenter-name">Test Name</span><span class="pull-right"><a id="78564610">Reply</a> <span class="small text-muted">Mar 29 2017, 00:59:57</span></span>
  <p class="list-group-item-text">First comment on page.</p>
</div>
```

Since the target span is prev of parent of a use `$(this).parent().prev('.commenter-name').text();`

Answer (score 0):

Use this. This is working.

```js
$("a").click(function() {
 var $test = $(this).closest('.list-group-item')
              .find('.commenter-name').text();
 alert($test);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group-item">
<span class="list-group-item-heading commenter-name">Test Name</span>

<span class="pull-right">
<br /><a id="78564610">Reply</a><br />

<span class="small text-muted">Mar 29 2017, 00:59:57</span></span>
<p class="list-group-item-text">First comment on page.</p>
</div>
```